# How do I capture the redirected url using mechanize?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm using mechanize to visit a link that will be redirected to another page, which provides the full-text pdf which I want to download. I tried to capture the final url using the following code:

`link = "http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/elink.fcgi?dbfrom=pubmed&retmode=ref&cmd=prlinks&id=29499174"`

`m = Mechanize.new { |a| a.keep_alive = 1 }`

`p = m.get(link)`

`uri = p.uri.to_s`

I expect uri to be the final link, but if what I captured (https://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0002-9394(18)30073-4) is different than what I found by using a browser (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0002939418300734?via%3Dihub)

What should I do to capture the final url? Related to that: I want to capture the final link since I need to use mechanize to click on the pdf link and download the paper. Can I do that without capturing the final url?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I came up with a crappy solution: it seems that for all the redirected urls, the final url is hidden in the meta, such as below:

```
[#<Mechanize::Page::MetaRefresh
""
 "/retrieve/articleSelectPrefsPerm?Redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2FS0161642009005387%3Fvia%253Dihub&key=9ea56f97a6b39bf4e5845b7c6186c7f7a2ea6b15">
]
```

so what I'm doing now is to use page.meta_refresh.to_s to grab the string, and then use gsub to extract the url and then use gsub to clean up the encoding.

I'm sure there are better ones out there - let me know if you have better ideas. Thanks!